# Passing coordinates to Google Maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-intent

I've stored the latitude and longitude value in the firebase and retrieve in the recycle view list with search function. I want it to display the location in google maps when the button map was clicked on each item based on each text view latitude and longitude value. How can I pass the value to the maps activity to display the location marker on the google maps.

SearchActivity.java

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
EditText EditTextZone;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
ArrayList<String> studentNameList;
ArrayList<String> studentMatrikList;
ArrayList<String> studentPhoneList;
ArrayList<String> studentAddressList;
ArrayList<String> studentLatitudeList;
ArrayList<String> studentLongitudeList;
SearchAdapter searchAdapter;
Button buttonCancel;
Button buttonGo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    EditTextZone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextZone);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    buttonCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
    buttonGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);

    buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonGo.setOnClickListener(this);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    studentNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    studentMatrikList = new ArrayList<>();
    studentPhoneList = new ArrayList<>();
    studentAddressList = new ArrayList<>();
    studentLatitudeList = new ArrayList<>();
    studentLongitudeList = new ArrayList<>();

    EditTextZone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){

                setAdapter(s.toString());

            } else {
                studentNameList.clear();
                studentMatrikList.clear();
                studentPhoneList.clear();
                studentAddressList.clear();
                studentLongitudeList.clear();
                studentLatitudeList.clear();
                recyclerView.removeAllViews();
            }

        }
    });


}

private void setAdapter(final String searchedString) {

    databaseReference.child("student").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            studentNameList.clear();
            studentMatrikList.clear();
            studentPhoneList.clear();
            studentAddressList.clear();
            studentLongitudeList.clear();
            studentLatitudeList.clear();
            recyclerView.removeAllViews();

            int counter = 0;

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String id = snapshot.getKey();
                String studentName = snapshot.child("studentName").getValue(String.class);
                String studentMatrik = snapshot.child("studentMatrik").getValue(String.class);
                String studentPhone = snapshot.child("studentPhone").getValue(String.class);
                String studentAddress = snapshot.child("studentAddress").getValue(String.class);
                String studentLongitude = snapshot.child("studentLongitude").getValue(String.class);
                String studentLatitude = snapshot.child("studentLatitude").getValue(String.class);


                if (studentAddress.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())) {

                    studentNameList.add(studentName);
                    studentMatrikList.add(studentMatrik);
                    studentPhoneList.add(studentPhone);
                    studentAddressList.add(studentAddress);
                    studentLatitudeList.add(studentLatitude);
                    studentLongitudeList.add(studentLongitude)
                    counter++;


                } else if (studentName.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())) {
                    studentNameList.add(studentName);
                    studentMatrikList.add(studentMatrik);
                    studentPhoneList.add(studentPhone);
                    studentAddressList.add(studentAddress);
                    studentLatitudeList.add(studentLatitude);
                    studentLongitudeList.add(studentLongitude);
                    counter++;
                }

                if (counter == 15)
                    break;
            }

            searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchActivity.this, studentNameList, studentMatrikList, studentPhoneList, studentAddressList, studentLongitudeList, studentLatitudeList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == buttonCancel)
    {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, UserAreaActivity.class));
    }

    if (v == buttonGo)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class));
    }

}
```

}

SearchAdapter.java

public class SearchAdapter extend RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
Context context;
ArrayList<String> studentNameList;
ArrayList<String> studentMatrikList;
ArrayList<String> studentPhoneList;
ArrayList<String> studentAddressList;
ArrayList<String> studentLatitudeList;
ArrayList<String> studentLongitudeList;

class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView studentName, studentMatrik, studentPhone, studentAddress, studentLongitude, studentLatitude;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    Button buttonMap;


    public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        studentName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
        studentMatrik = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentMatrik);
        studentPhone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentPhone);
        studentAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentAddress);
        studentLongitude = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentLongitude);
        studentLatitude = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentLatitude);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        buttonMap = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMap);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(SearchAdapter.this.context,
                            "Selected student is " + studentName.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
    }

}

public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> studentNameList, ArrayList<String> studentMatrikList, ArrayList<String> studentPhoneList, ArrayList<String> studentAddressList, ArrayList<String> studentLongitudeList, ArrayList<String> studentLatitudeList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.studentNameList = studentNameList;
    this.studentMatrikList = studentMatrikList;
    this.studentPhoneList = studentPhoneList;
    this.studentAddressList = studentAddressList;
    this.studentLongitudeList = studentLongitudeList;
    this.studentLatitudeList = studentLatitudeList;

}

@Override
public SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
    return new SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.studentName.setText(studentNameList.get(position));
    holder.studentMatrik.setText(studentMatrikList.get(position));
    holder.studentPhone.setText(studentPhoneList.get(position));
    holder.studentAddress.setText(studentAddressList.get(position));
    holder.studentLatitude.setText(studentLatitudeList.get(position));
    holder.studentLongitude.setText(studentLongitudeList.get(position));
    holder.buttonMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,MapViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Latitude", studentLatitudeList);
            intent.putExtra("Longitude", studentLongitudeList);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return studentNameList.size();
}
```

Maps Activity

```
public class MapViewActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
            .title("Marker"));
}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass data from one activity to second activity ?

Comment: where you used searchadapter

Comment: @Aditya Sonel yes I want to pass the latitude and longitude in search activity to the maps activity

Comment: @JavaGuy check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well your approach of making the list in not good to me. I will suggest to make one data model for the recycler view.

Lets come to your question, I have seen that you have passed the longitude and latitude to the MapViewActivity so here is the way to go (Just copy past following code and replace any typing mistake in syntax)

```
public class MapViewActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {   
private double latitude,longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    latitude = Double.parseDouble(extras.getString("Latitude"));
    longitude = Double.parseDouble(extras.getString("Longitude"));
    //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title("Marker"));
```

}

try it , it must work.

Comment: it return to main activity?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass  `studentLatitudeList` as list

**pass the data**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();  
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("studentLatitudeList", studentLatitudeList);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("studentLongitudeList", studentLongitudeList);
```

studentLongitudeList
**retrieve data**

```
public class MapViewActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {   


    ArrayList<String> studentLatitudeList;
    ArrayList<String> studentLongitudeList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        studentLatitudeList= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("studentLatitudeList");
        studentLongitudeList= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("studentLongitudeList");

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        for(int i=0;i<studentLatitudeList.size();i++)
        {
        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(studentLatitudeList.get(i));
        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(studentLongitudeList.get(i));
         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title("Marker"));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MapViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Latitude", studentLatitudeList);
        intent.putExtra("Longitude", studentLongitudeList);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Receive in `MapActivity`

```
    String Latitude = getIntent().getStringExtra("Latitude");
    String Longitude = getIntent().getStringExtra("Longitude");
    double lat=Double.parseDouble(Latitude);
    double lng=Double.parseDouble(Longitude);


   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
        .title("Marker"));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to pass data between activities like `shared-preferences`, `database`, `static classes` but the simplest method is by passing data through `Intent`.

Let two activities `Activity A` and `Activity B`. Now, we have to pass data from `Activity A` to `Activity B`.

So, in `Activity A`,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putFloat("latitude", latitudeValue);
intent.putFloat("longitude", longitudeValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now, to receive data in `Activity B`,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Float latitude = intent.getFloat("latitude");
Float longitude = intent.getFloat("longitude");
```